# Every Solution set of Homogeneous system is a linear combination of fundamental solutions

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove: Every Solution set of Homogeneous system is a linear combination of fundamental solution.

can I say that the fundamental solution is a trivial basis therefore is spans the Null space? can I take an example of a solution like $(-t-s,s,t)=t(-1,0,1)+s(-1,1,0) $ 
are those claims are valid?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

It can be easily checked that a set of all solutions of a homogeneous system of linear equations is a linear space. Therefore it contains a basis, whose 
members can be considered as fundamental solutions.